# how to search for a column value from excel in python

Tags: python, excel, search, python-2.7

Sl No , Task , Date , Hrs

1 ,Proxy bid new flow of accepting all the bids as proxy bid started,12-Nov-12, 8hrs

2 ,Proxy bid new flow of accepting all the bids as proxy bid completed in local machine,14-Nov-12   4hrs

3 ,Proxy bid new flow of accepting all the bids as proxy bid uploaded in test server and then in Live server and testing done,16-Nov-12 ,6hrs

This is how my excel sheet looks like , Now I want to create a function in python which will take the input parameter of Date or also may be the Task and will return the Hrs.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're probably going to need to use another module like [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) or [xlutils](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlutils).  The documentation on pandas is very good and should walk you through your process.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code. suppose f1.csv is the file.

```
import os

str1 = '"Proxy bid new flow of accepting all the bids as proxy bid started"'

def get_hours(str1):
   cmd1 = 'grep -R '+str1 +' f.csv'
   result = os.popen(cmd1).read()
   hrs = result.split(',')[-1]
   print hrs
   return hrs

get_hours(str1)
```